# How do trigger a component to render in Angular 2 after update property via another component? ngZone.run() is not working

Tags: angular

I am having a problem getting a component to re-render. I have a breadcrumb component that I want other components to be able to update it by calling a method. E.g. say I have a ViewContact component, I want that component to set the active page in the breadcrumb to be the name of the contact.

The breadcrumb component is being injected into the ViewContact component & I've set up the provider for the breadcrumb. The ViewContact component is calling a method on the breadcrumb component which is in turn calling `ngZone.run()` as I've read should trigger the component to re-render. However it isn't.

I've created a simple Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rWZ8ZGqmda1cieDmsc2s

Is what I'm trying to do achievable using injection or is there a better way?

Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can't inject the `Breadcrumb` component into the `OtherComponent` one since they don't have a parent / child relation. This won't work even if you add the first component into providers:

```
providers: [Breadcrumb],
```

Either you choose the approach provided by Günter, either you choose a shared service:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class SharedService {
  property:string;
  property$:Subject<string> = new Subject();

  setProperty(newValue:string) {
    this.property = newValue;
    this.property$.next(this.property);
  }
}
```

In the components you will use this service this way:

```
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {
  count: number = 1;

  constructor( private service: SharedService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateBreadcrumb();
  }

  updateBreadcrumb() {
    this.service.setProperty("changed " + (this.count++));
  }
}

(...)

export class Breadcrumb {
  @Input() testProperty: string = "Initial Value which hopefully will get changed";  

  constructor(private service:SharedService) {
    this.service.property$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.testProperty = data;
    });
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/wPEnpTWeMM1qpQPyzpdc?p=preview.

This doc regarding component interaction could interest you:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Many thanks for your quick assistance!! I have this now working in the app I'm working on. I'll definitely give that article a read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `EventEmitter` and template variables to communicate between siblings.

```
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() notifyOther:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  ...

  updateBreadcrumb() {
    this.notifyOther.emit("changed " + (this.count++));
    //this._breadcrumb.setProperty("changed " + (this.count++));
  }
}
```

```
<breadcrumb #breadCrumb></breadcrumb>

<other-component (notifyOther)="breadCrumb.testProperty = $event"></other-component>
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lNUm6NZmu0M68Uelw4Mh?p=preview)

Comment: This might work in the simple scenario but in my application I have a component which contains the breadcrumb component & a RouterOutlet. 

`<breadcrumb></breadcrumb>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

The component then loads other components such as the ViewContact component. The breadcrumb can render items based on the route name (`router.currentInstruction.component.routeName`)

Comment: Then Thierries answer is probably what you're looking for.